# Using jQuery to stretch an image to fill entire div, which resizes on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize, responsive-design

I know this has been asked in some way before, but none of the solutions I can find quite do everything, and I'm struggling to mix them up.

I have a webpage made up of a series of panels, and I'm using jQuery to resize each panel to fill the document window, and resize again if the window is resized.

In some of the panels I have images, and I'd like the images to fill the entire div, without skewing, and to resize when the window is resized.

I have managed to get the image to resize with the width of the window, but if the window becomes too long, there is empty space below the image.

It might be made slightly more complicated by the fact that some of the panels are slideshows using the jQuery cycle plugin.

Here's some code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel-one" class="panel">

    <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-slides="> div">

        <div id="slide-one" class="slide">

            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/blmiers2/6128832572/" title="Grizzly Bear - Animal - Wildlife - Alaska by blmiers2, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6077/6128832572_c46d6ecace_b.jpg" width="1024" height="683" alt="Grizzly Bear - Animal - Wildlife - Alaska"></a>

        </div><!--#slide-one-->

    <div id="slide-two" class="slide">

            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/peterlee79/5146115834/" title="Bear by Peter Lee(&amp;#51060;&amp;#50896;&amp;#55148;), on Flickr"><img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1320/5146115834_9bb65ea57d_b.jpg" width="760" height="507" alt="Bear"></a>

        </div><!--#slide-two-->

        <div id="slide-three" class="slide">

           <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/upim/305578292/" title="bear by Timo Heuer, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/119/305578292_2f249d9de3_b.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="bear"></a>

        </div><!--#slide-three-->

    </div><!--.cycle-slideshow-->

</div><!--#panel-one-->

<div id="panel-two" class="panel">

    <div class="content">

    I'm panel two 

    </div><!--.content-->

</div><!--#panel-two-->

<div id="panel-three" class="panel">

    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/lobstermassage/25347643/" title="Bear by CiroNT, on Flickr"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/23/25347643_cac744b73a_b.jpg" width="1024" height="680" alt="Bear"></a>

 </div><!--#panel-three-->
```

​
**CSS:**

```
.panel {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

#panel-one {
background: #888;    
}

#panel-two {
background: #84c6d6;
}

#panel-three {
background: #444;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){

    $('.panel, .cycle-slide, .slide').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});

    $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.panel, .cycle-slide, .slide').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
    });

});


 div = $(".panel");
   imgsrc = div.find('img').attr('src');

   var img = new Image()
   img.onload = function(){
        imgw = img.width;
        imgh = img.height;

        resizeMyImg(imgw,imgh);
        div.find('img').show();

        $(window).resize(function(){ resizeMyImg(imgw,imgh) });

        }

   img.src = imgsrc

   function resizeMyImg(w,h){     
      //the width is larger
      if (w > h) {
        //resize the image to the div
        div.find('img').width(div.innerWidth() + 'px').height('auto');
      }        
      else {
        // the height is larger or the same
        //resize the image to the div
        div.find('img').height(div.innerHeight() + 'px').width('auto');
      }

     }
```

​
And here's a fiddle of where I'm up to: http://jsfiddle.net/pwQdV/

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use version 2 of the cycle.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

```
.cycle-slideshow img {
    display : block;
    width : 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mBDyH/

Answer (score 0):

if you want no blank space, then you'll have to resize based on the image's *smallest* dimension, not the largest dimension.  This will mean that, in most cases, your image will be sized so that it overflows your div on one dimension, and exactly matches your div on the other dimension.  If you set `overflow: hidden` on your div, it'll effectively crop the overflowing portion of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwQdV/9/

```
// notice: `h` and `w` are swapped here...
if (h > w) {
    //resize the image to the div
    div.find('img').width(div.innerWidth() + 'px').height('auto');
} else {
    // the height is larger or the same
    //resize the image to the div
    div.find('img').height(div.innerHeight() + 'px').width('auto');
}
```